# Codeigniter sessions (ion_auth) not keeping after redirect

Tags: codeigniter, google-chrome, session, codeigniter-3, ion-auth

On my Android device running Chrome my sessions never saved after redirect with Ion Auth and I consistently get a new session id. This issue is not persistent on other mobile versions of Chrome, desktop versions of Chrome, or another android device that I have running Chrome.

When all else failed I dumped my site onto another (free) production server and it works there. It is important to note that this issue is *unique* to this one device I have. I have cleared Chrome entirely, when that didn't work I reset the Android device completely.

So I have a few interesting troubleshooting issues:

1. System works on all other devices I could test it on except this one device that has been factory reset to eliminate any transient cookies as an issue
2. On the device in question the system works when it is on a different production server.

What could be the issue? What troubleshooting steps can I take to narrow down the issue?

Config:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'fagardesigns_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 86400;
$config['sess_save_path'] = dirname(ROOT) . DS . '_sessions_' . DS;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;


$config['cookie_prefix'] = 'nc';
$config['cookie_domain'] = '.fagardesigns.com';
$config['cookie_path'] = '/';
$config['cookie_secure'] = FALSE;
$config['cookie_httponly'] = FALSE;
```

Aside from device resetting additional steps taken:

- I cleared all of my browser data in mobile, still the issue persists.
- I deleted all my session files, still nothing.
- I renamed my sess_cookie_name
- I made a new sessions dir
- Session recheck timer in ion_auth is OFF (always has been)

System specs:

CI: 3.1.7

PHP (prod): 5.6 (same issues on 7)

Ion_Auth: latest version

Comment: try to send flashdata session msge before the redirect

Comment: Seems to me that server differences should be investigated. Start by comparing the php.ini files of both servers.

Comment: Firewall blocking the one server but not the other? Anti-virus software on the troublesome device?

Comment: What to look out for in php.ini? Firewall would be strange as it would effect other devices trying to login on the same network and that isn't a problem so I don't think that's it. Antivirus not on the device.

Comment: I get the "Wrong credentials!" message with both ajax and regular post. There is also a var_dump of the session data.

Comment: Sorry username admin password is password !